# Fuzzy String Matching in R on numbers separated by hyphens

Tags: r, agrep

I am trying to match Cell Phone Tower IDs contained in one table with a master table of locations(in lat long) of Cell Phone Tower IDs. The format of IDs in the locations table are different from the ones in the first table and I am trying to use `agrep()` to do a fuzzy match. To give you an example, let's say the ID I am trying to match is:

```
x <- c("405-800-125-39883")
```

A sample of IDs located in the locations table:

```
y <- c("405-810-1802-19883", "405-810-2101-29883", "405-810-1401-31883",
       "405-810-5005-49883","125-39883","405-810-660-39883")
```

I am then using `agrep()` with different combinations of `max.distance`:

```
agrep(x,y,max.distance=0.3,value=TRUE)
```

This returns:

```
[1] "405-810-1802-19883" "405-810-2101-29883" "405-810-1401-31883" "405-810-5005-49883"
[5] "405-810-660-39883"
```

Whereas the value that I am really after is `"125-39883"`
I have also tried the `stringdist_join()` function from the `stringdist` package and applied to the two data frames bby varying `max_dist` but with no success. Basically what I am looking for is a perfect match after the last hyphen and then macth on the number on the second last hyphen and so on. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: If yo uare looking for an exact match then strip off the substring and then do `==` `y[y == substring(x, 9)]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun but not quite. The data I have shared is just a sample for demonstration. Your solution will work for this particular example. However, the value might also be stored as `"800-125-39883"` or as `"5-800-125-39883"`. So can't really specify 9 in `substring()`

Comment: The problem is that in agrep or others, it is matching for the other digits and it can't really differentiate between the last few elements.  Ir ia better to provide example with all the cases

Comment: @akrun Just thinking aloud here, but do you think splitting on "-" and then matching by starting from the last value would help? I feel it might but not sure how to do that.

Comment: It is still not clear to me which numbers you are matching

Comment: If you look at any ID of a cell tower, it is broken into 4 parts. For example, in 405-810-1802-19883, 405 is the Country Code, 810 is the Mobile Network Code, 1802 is the Location Area Code (LAC) and 19883 is the Cell ID. I would first like to match the Cell ID, but because it will not be unique as different states in the country could have the same Cell IDs, I would then match on LAC. I have already filtered for the Mobile network code and the country code.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorized `agrep` to be able to use all the values of y as the pattern.
Your aim is to look for the whole of y as a part of x. Thus your pattern should be y and not x

```
names(unlist(Vectorize(agrep)(y,x)))
[1] "125-39883"
```

Although we can use `adist` with the argument `partial=TRUE` so that it may do exactly what `agrep` does:

```
 y[which.min(c(adist(y,x,partial = T)))]
    [1] "125-39883"
```

If `x` is a vector and `y` is also a vector, you would rather use `adist` instead of `agrep`. All the arguments of `agrep` are contained in `adist`. Check `?adist` for further details.

with your new question in the comments, you can do something like this:

```
w=adist(y,x,partial=T)
z=setNames(nchar(sub(".*?(M*)$","\\1",c(attr(adist(y,x,counts=T),"trafos")))),y)
names(which.max(z[which(min(w)==w)]))
[1] "126-39883"
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu. However I think I should be matching on the last set of numbers. For example, if `y <- c("405-810-1802-19883", "405-810-2101-29883", "405-810-1401-31883",
       "405-810-5005-49883","125-49883","405-810-660-39883","126-39883")` then the result I would be interested in would be `"126-39883"` rather than `"125-49883"` that your code returns.

Comment: The problem is you did not state this in your original question. Always ensure to give an example that captures your problem

Comment: Agreed, my bad.